# Viewing Mount Everest in the shortest possible time

Tags: nepal, mount-everest

I have only three days to stay in Nepal and I want to see Mount Everest from as close as I can. In this short time frame how can I do it?

Comment: I'd look at helicopter tours, not cheap, but would be your best option.

Answer (score 8):

[Discover Nepal, the official tourism site for the country,](https://www.welcomenepal.com/plan-your-trip/see-everest.html) also recommends flying (as did @Max):

> For those on a tight time-frame taking a [mountain flight](https://www.welcomenepal.com/things-to-do/mountain-flights.html) from Kathmandu is by far the easiest and quickest way to see Everest. It's as simple as arriving in Kathmandu on day one and booking a flight for the next morning. You'll be flying right beside the world’s highest peaks including an up close fly-by of Everest.

Flights are offered by Nepal's domestic airlines:

- [Budda Airlines Mountain Experience](https://www.buddhaair.com/mountain-flight-nepal/everest-experience.html)
- [Yeti Airlines Everest Express](https://www.yetiairlines.com/destination/everest-express)
- [Simrik Airlines Mountain Flight](http://simrikairlines.com/services-2/)

Among the scores of articles you’ll find on the subject, the KimKim* travel app site offers this concise list and map of [Nepal’s Top 6 Viewpoints](https://www.kimkim.com/c/nepal-s-best-viewpoints-where-to-see-everest-and-other-himalayan-giants) (and excerpted for brevity):

> **1. Kala Patthar, Everest Region**
>
> Kala Patthar, near Everest Basecamp, remains the top viewpoint in Nepal. It offers the closest view on Mount Everest one can get to without serious mountaineering skills. Alternatively, you can take a helicopter ride from Lukla or even directly from Kathmandu.
>
> **2. Khopra Ridge, Annapurna Region**
>
> Khopra Ridge offers spectacular views of Dhaulagiri, the world's 7th highest mountain. Visiting Khopra Danda requires about 6 days of trekking.
>
> **3. Gokyo Ri, Everest Region**
>
> A rocky peak at 5,357m above sea level, Gokyo Ri is the slightly lesser known, and slightly farther away viewpoint of Everest compared to its more famous sibling Kala Patthar. Trekking to Gokyo Ri takes about 14 days round trip from Lukla, via Namche Bazaar and Gokyo Lakes.
>
> **4. Pikey Peak, Everest Region**
>
> Pikey Peak offers an even farther away, and thus more encompassing view of Everest and the surrounding mountains. Edmund Hillary, part of Mt Everest's first ascend team, declared this viewpoint the best in Nepal. Trekking to Pikey Peak is a highly recommended off the beaten path experience through the lower Everest Region that requires about 6 days. You can also reach Pikey Peak by mountain bike.
>
> **5. Tengboche, Everest Region**
>
> A famous Buddhist monastery above Sherpa capital Namche Bazaar at 3,867m above sea level, Tengboche offers amazing views of Ama Dablam, by many considered the world's most beautiful mountain. Getting to Tengboche requires a 5-day trek starting from Lukla via Namche Bazaar.
>
> **6. Nagarkot, Kathmandu Valley**
>
> If you are short on time and want to stay close to Kathmandu while still enjoying amazing views of the Himalayas, Nagarkot is your best bet. Nagarkot is just a short 1-hour drive away from Kathmandu.
>
> **7. Poon Hill, Annapurna Region**
>
> Located above the village of Ghorepani in the Annapurna region of Nepal, Poon Hill is the most visited viewpoint in this list. It offers spectacular sunrise views of Dhaulagiri and Annapurna, but you'll likely have to share these views with at least one hundred fellow trekkers. It's relatively easily accessible via the lower Annapurna trail system and can be done in about 3 - 4 days round trip from Pokhara.

[image]

- No affiliation.

Comment: I really fail to see what all that stuff from the travel app adds to the answer as none of the viewpoints fits the criteria in the question: either you can't see Everest from them or it takes well over three days to get there.

Comment: (+1) Great info though, it might be worth creating another question just to highlight it, I would upvote that.